# PHP cURL not not saving videos on Windows 8

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get files from an rss feed XML, change the name of them and store them locally on a Window 8 machine.  It runs perfectly in MAMP on OS X but when I run the same code in WAMP the files are 0 bytes, just the file name is there from the fopen() command.

```
$content = $domain . $feed;


$file = file_get_contents($content);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($file);


for ($x = 0; $x < $max; $x++) {
    $link = $xml->channel->item[$x]->link;

    $i = explode("/", $link); 
    set_time_limit(0);  
    $fileName = 'videos/video-' . $i[7] .'.mp4';

    if (!file_exists($fileName)){ 
        $fp = fopen($fileName, 'w+');
        $url = $link;    
        $ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
};


echo $file;
```

---

This is in a .php file called by AJAX and it meant to download the videos then the echo $file creates an XML file that is further parsed by JS.  The point being the files are then local not on the internet if the connection goes down.  This works perfectly on OS X in MAMP. It is on Windows and AMP that It does not work, it has something to do with the cURL command and the directory buy I am not familiar with cURL in anyway to be able to troubleshoot.

Comment: I don't know what a cli script is so I can't answer that.

Comment: CLI is a command line interface. Do you run it from browser or from command line?

Comment: It is in a php file.

Comment: And how do you run this script, from browser? Do you have some errors in log file?

Comment: Add this line at the script beginning:

`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: I have error reporting on and there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add next curl options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
```

Also try to change line `$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));` to `$ch = curl_init(urlencode($url));`

Comment: Thanks but this didn't help.  I am still getting 0 byte files.

Comment: Could you please show response info? Before line `curl_close($ch);` insert next code `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)); die();`. Run it and show an output.

Comment: It will not let me post the result as it is too long by 176 characters.

Comment: You can share the result using http://pastebin.com/ or http://pastie.org/ or some other service.

Answer (score 0):

Add next options for writing download result to a file:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There were two things I seemed to be missing as it now works.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

and I also needed to close fopen().

```
fclose($fp);
```

The files were on a self signed certificate and apparently cURL doesn't like that.